# Why did they choose Jar Jar Binks as the Gungan Representative of Naboo?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones, jar-jar-binks

Now, we all know the out of universe reason for Jar Jar's ongoing existence, but apart from "he was friends with the Senator and a few Jedi", why would Naboo have risked putting Jar Jar in front of the Galactic Senate as the Gungan representative for Naboo?

In the movies and in *every* episode of *The Clone Wars* in which he appears, he does something stupid and by pure dumb luck manages to survive or achieve some random success with his clumsiness rather than any skill as a statesman.

In-universe, I can't see any planetary government wanting him to be the representative for his species.  There surely are far more qualified and capable Gungans who would be a far better choice.  Jar Jar could have been given some local fiefdom for his part in the liberating of Naboo.

So my question is, **What *in-universe* reason would there be for Naboo choosing Jar Jar Binks to be the Gungan Representative in the Galactic Senate?**

Comment: To keep  him off the planet?  /s

Comment: Yet more evidence for the Darth Jar Jar hypothesis...

Comment: Clearly he has the Teela Brown gene.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [Star Wars: Attack of the Clones - Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Attack_of_the_Clones_The_Visual_Dictionary), Jar Jar was regarded as a war hero as well as the ambassadorial genius who brokered the new agreement between the Naboobians and the Gungans. His "simple heart" and a "tide of goodwill" elevated him into a role far beyond his capabilities.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also worth noting: Weird and luck-driven as his entire nature was...you couldn't deny that his luck never really ran out on him. Sure, he lucked his way into everything he ever accomplished...but he had the devil's own luck, and never really failed at accomplishing something he was sent forth to do. Even if it never, ever went as planned.

Comment: @guildsbounty - His vast stupidity resulted in the deaths of trillions.

Comment: Yes...but at the time, it was viewed as a "good" move by most of the people in authority. After all, his 'motion for emergency powers' was passed by the rest of the senate. He may have been the one who introduced the idea...but he certainly wasn't the only one responsible. It wasn't until people in-universe were looking back that they may have realized how he had been manipulated.

Comment: My head canon is Palpatine, as Supreme Chancellor and being from Naboo, probably had some political influence getting him appointed. Jar Jar could be (and arguably was) easily manipulated into furthering Palpatine's agenda.

Comment: @MichaelItzoe - I don't doubt that if Jar Jar was actually a shrewd (but liberal) political operator, Palpatine would have used his influence to have him killed/sidelined/discredited

Comment: So I woke up this morning, and I was _sure_ that my question would have been answered, and answered by Richard. Nice answer :)